# How can I place 5 plots symmetrically in one figure?

Tags: pdftex

I am writing a paper wherein I have to place five plots in one figure. My figure currently looks like this:

| plot 1  |  plot 2  |  plot 3 |

|  plot 4  |  plot 5  |

The image in the second row (fig 4) starts from the margin whereas I want fig 4 and 5 in the center of the row. I have been using tabular option so far and I realized that I wouldn't get my desired figure with tabular. Can anyone suggest a way I can get the desired format of figure? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Placement of images in row using subfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132599/placement-of-images-in-row-using-subfigure)

Comment: Do you need subcaptions for the plots?

Comment: Yes. I will require sub captions as well

Answer (score 3):

Using the `subcaption` package, you can enclose everything in a single `figure` environment and use `subfigure` environments for your separate plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
% plot 1
\caption{Caption 1} % subcaptions aren't mandatory
\end{subfigure} \quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
% plot 2
\end{subfigure} \quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
% plot 3
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
% plot 4
\end{subfigure}\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
% plot 5
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Hello, world.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

See also: [documentation for `subcaption` package](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf).

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted with the subfigure package. Thanks anyway!