# How to add two figures in the same row

Tags: graphics, document-configuration

I am trying to make two figures adjacent in the same row but have no idea how to do this. I used following tex code but it adds only one figure in a row. Kindly help me. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height= 2.5cm, width=8cm]{figA.eps}
\caption{}\label{}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132599/14103

Comment: Please complete your example so we can compile it. What needs to be added depends partly on the class and on any other relevant packages loaded. If you are using a standard class, you might want something like **subcaption** or **floatrow**. But if you just want two images in one figure, you can just add another `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Do you want what is called "sub figures"? Or do you just want two images next to one another.

Comment: @Werner I want two images next to one another.

Comment: @monalisa: Just put the commands next to one another: `\includegraphics[..]{...} \hspace{<len>} \includegraphics[..]{...}` where you specify the distance `<len>` that should separate them. Of course, if your images are stretched to `8cm` in width, then there's not much room left horizontally, if any. If that's the case, they'll wrap around since they can't fit within the text block.

Comment: Use subfigures (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the following approach:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{figA.eps}
\hspace{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{figB.eps}
\caption{xyz}\label{fig:xyz}
\end{figure}
```

i.e., I would use *relative* rather than absolute widths for the graphs. With the parameters chosen above, 5% of the width of the textblock will be used as whitespace between graphs A and B; hopefully that'll be enough.

Comment: that's lovely....!! but how to reduce the size of figure as its taking too much of space on the page

Comment: @monalisa - Please clarify what you mean by the figure "taking [up] too much of space". It does fit inside the width of the textblock, doesn't it? Or is it too tall for your taste?

Comment: I mean size of pic is too big.

Comment: @monalisa - Please clarify what you mean by "too big" -- horizontally, vertically, or in both directions?

Comment: Oh sorry for so late reply. I meant vertically.... u may say height of pic

Comment: @monalisa -- Please try replacing the two `[width=0.475\textwidth]` options with `[width=0.475\textwidth,height=2.5cm,keepaspectratio]`. (Feel free to replace `2.5cm` with your preferred value for the height of the images.)