# Problem in side-by-side figures plotting

Tags: subfloats, plot

Why does the below code not allow to print the two figures side by side, but one below each other?

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.12\linewidth,height=5.8cm]{Martingale_check_BS_1MLN_iterations.png}
\subcaption{1-year leap}
\label{fig:martingality check BS. 1-year leap}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.12\linewidth,height=5.8cm] 
{Martingale_check_BS_1MLN_iterations_1monthleap.png}
\subcaption{1-month leap}
\label{fig:martingality check BS. 1-month leap}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Martingality property check for BS}
\label{fig:Martingality property check for BS}

\end{figure}
```

Could this depend on the two specific images?

Comment: This may also qualify as a FAQ.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132599/placement-of-images-in-row-using-subfigure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two successive line feeds between your two `subfigure` environments. This instructs Latex to insert a new paragraph. If you delete the empty line or comment the line out the result is as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\dummy{%
    \tikz{\draw[fill=green] (0,0) rectangle(\linewidth, 5.8cm);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \dummy
        \subcaption{1-year leap}
        \label{fig:martingality check BS. 1-year leap}
    \end{subfigure}%
%
% <---- Comments prevent the insertion of
%       a new paragraph with \par
%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \dummy
        \subcaption{1-month leap}
        \label{fig:martingality check BS. 1-month leap}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Martingality property check for BS}
    \label{fig:Martingality property check for BS}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You a lot